# Getting unknown property error in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I know there are some answers related to this, but I couldn't find any useful ones.

I am getting this error: `Getting unknown property: app\models\Employees::holidays` and I've no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Could someone help me out to solve this?

This is my model code:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

/**
* This is the model class for table "employee".
*
* @property integer $id
* @property string $name
* @property string $surname
* @property string $employment_date
*/
 class Employee extends ActiveRecord
{
/** @const SCENARIO_CREATE scenario - create */
const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';

/** @const SCENARIO_EDIT scenario - edit */
const SCENARIO_EDIT = 'edit';

/** @const SCENARIO_SEARCH scenario - search */
const SCENARIO_SEARCH = 'search';

/** @const HOLIDAYS_PER_WORK_DAY Earned holidays per one working day. */
const HOLIDAYS_PER_WORK_DAY = 0.4;

/** @var integer $holidays calculated holidays field used in list. */
public $holidays;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'employee';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // id
        ['id', 'required', 'except' => self::SCENARIO_SEARCH],
        ['id', 'integer'],

        // name
        ['name', 'required'],
        ['name', 'string', 'max' => 255],

        // surname
        ['surname', 'required'],
        ['surname', 'string', 'max' => 255],

        // employment date
        ['employment_date', 'required'],
        ['employment_date', 'match',
            'pattern' => '/^([1][9]|[2][0])[0-9]{2}[-](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-](0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/',
            'message' => Yii::t('app',
                'Neteisingas datos formatas (Formatas: YYYY-MM-DD)'),
        ],
        ['employment_date', 'date',
            'format' => 'php:Y-m-d',
            'max' => time(),
            'tooBig' => Yii::t('app', 'Blogai įvesta  data. Vėliausia galima data: ' . date('Y-m-d'))
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
        'name' => Yii::t('app', 'Darbuotojo vardas'),
        'surname' => Yii::t('app', 'Darbuotojo pavardė'),
        'employment_date' => Yii::t('app', 'Įdarbinimo data'),
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_CREATE => [
            'name',
            'surname',
            'employment_date',
        ],
        self::SCENARIO_EDIT => [
            'id',
            'name',
            'surname',
            'employment_date',
        ],
        self::SCENARIO_SEARCH => [
            'id',
            'name',
            'surname',
            'employment_date',
            'holidays',
        ],
    ];
}
/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $holidays = 'floor(datediff(curdate(), employment_date) * ' . 
Employee::HOLIDAYS_PER_WORK_DAY . ')';

    $query = Employees::find()->select([
        $this->tableName() . '.id',
        $this->tableName() . '.name',
        $this->tableName() . '.surname',
        $this->tableName() . '.employment_date',
        $holidays . ' as holidays',
    ]);

    // add conditions that should always apply here
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => ['name' => SORT_ASC],
        ],
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'employment_date' => $this->employment_date,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'surname', $this->surname]);

    return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

My index.php file:

```
<?php

use app\models\EmployeeSearch;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\web\View;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
/* @var $this View */
/* @var $searchModel EmployeeSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Employees');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="employee-index">

<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<p>
    <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Employee'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</p>
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'name',
        'surname',
        'employment_date',
        'holidays',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
   ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?></div>
```

I know it's a quite long, but I don't know how much of the code I should include.

I think this line `holidays` in `index php` file is causing the error.

Comment: Call the variable with `$this->holidays`

Comment: If you're saying to change `$this->holidays'` instead of  `$holidays .  'as holidays'`, I just tried that, but it doesnt work

Comment: Can you show the code where you call this property?

Comment: @Bizley could you tell me in which place I have to `call a property`? Sorry for question like that, but just trying to learn

Comment: I guess you are not calling it directly. I think you should remove it from `self::SCENARIO_SEARCH` key in `scenarios()` since this is read-only property.

Comment: @Bizley I just deleted `holidays` from `self::SCENARIO_SEARCH`, but the error is still the same. Im confused

Comment: I just found exact problem which is causing the error. It's caused because of trying to add a new `column holidays` in `index.php`. But i need that column, how should I add it?

Comment: Show this `index.php`

Comment: Post edited with index.php

Comment: You need to fill this property using [afterFind()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterFind()-detail) or in GridView you can set how this column is filled with [value](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#grid-columns) key.

Answer (score 1):

Add this on your rule .

```
['holidays', 'integer']
```

And use this `$this->holidays` during search.

Answer (score 0):

you must comment all your `index.php` file and run your code. if you have not any error it means error is in `index.php` page.
then you must uncomment lines one by one and after each uncomment run your project.when you have error it means that line is one of your errors. then keep comment that line and uncomment other one by one and repeat that task to end of file.
in this way you can find your error.

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange with your code:

My assumption is that you have 2 different models:
"Employee" and "Employees" in your app/models directory.

You are using "Employees" model in the search() of "Employee". For this to work you need to define:

```
public $holidays;
```

in your "Employees" model as your error suggests.

But my guess is that you wanted to use maybe "Employee" model for the search(). If this is the case, change the "Employees" to "Employee" in that function:

```
$query = Employee::find()...
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the property for holidays in the model before class started:

`@property string $holidays`

Then it will work.